# How can I make \chapter (or other command) do nothing?

Tags: chapters

I tried `renewcommand` like this:

```
\renewcommand\chapter{}
```

But when I write `\chapter{test}` in my document there still is text "test" just without any formatting.

Comment: In general, if you want something to do nothing, use`\relax` it is a control sequence which does nothing. It is not expandable, which means, it stays the same. It is useful if anything cant be empty or if you want to indicate that there wont be anything more. i.e. if you use `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil` this can cause an error if the next word begins with an l, which leads to `fill` which exists also. Therefore you insert `\relax` after `fil`.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: Well, `in general` is not correct. Try to use `\let\chapter\relax` in a very simple `book` document.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just wanted to introduce the `\relax`. It took me pretty long to get what it's good for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just using `\renewcommand{\chapter}{}` would leave the moving arguments in the stream input, getting them typeset, e.g.

`\chapter{foo}` would yield `\chapter` empty `{foo}` argument is no argument any longer, but a typeset text, i.e. `foo` would be printed.

`\chapter` itself doesn't have arguments, but branches into `\@chapter` and `\@schapter`, depending on the version `\chapter` and `\chapter*`.

The starred chapter is using `\@schapter`, having one argument, whereas `\@chapter` has one optional and one mandatory argument. (statements true for `book` and `report` class, `memoir` is a little bit different.)
I'll present two solutions: The easier one with `\RenewDocumentCommand` and a more basic one with catching `\@chapter` and `\@chapter`.

This does absolutely nothing in the `document` body: It swallows the `\chapter*` etc. type of macros and their macros.

It catches the starred version (s), the optional argument (o) and the `mandatory` argument and leaves it doing absolutely nothing, so even `\tableofcontents` will not print a header (it uses `\chapter*{\contentsname}`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Here's a way without using `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{book}


\makeatletter

%\def\chapter%

% branches into \@chapter and \@schapter

\renewcommand{\@chapter}[2][]{%
}
\renewcommand{\@schapter}[1]{%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[foo]{Foobar}
\end{document}
```

Using `\let\chapter\relax` is of course also no good idea!

Now: The general question about letting some command doing nothing depends on the type of the macro. An argumentless macro,say `\foo` can be silenced with `\let\foo\relax`.

Comment: I haven't expected such a full answer, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Under the regular document class that have `\chapter`s, you'll have to *capture* three possible arguments:

1. `*`, as in `\chapter*{<title>}`
2. Optional argument `[`..`]`, as in `\chapter[<toc>]{<title>}`
3. Mandatory argument `{`...`}`, as in `\chapter{<title>}`.

Note that the above three arguments can be intermixed/used together, as in `\chapter*[<toc>]{<title>}`. To make `\chapter` a no-op, you can use any of the following methods:

1. [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

   ```
   \usepackage{xparse}
   \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{}
   \RenewDocumentCommand{\tableofcontents}{}{}
   \RenewDocumentCommand{\listoffigures}{}{}
   \RenewDocumentCommand{\listoftables}{}{}
   ```
2. LaTeX2e macro redefinitions:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand{\chapter}{\@ifstar\@chapter\@chapter}
   \renewcommand{\@chapter}[2][]{}
   \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{}% or \let\tableofcontents\relax
   \renewcommand{\listoffigures}{}% or \let\listoffigures\relax
   \renewcommand{\listoftables}{}% or \let\listoftables\relax
   \makeatother
   ```

In both instances the ToC-related commands may have to be suppressed as well to avoid setting (even a fictitious) ToC.

---

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) uses four possible arguments:

1. `*`, as in `\chapter*{<title>}`
2. First optional argument `[`.`]`, as in `\chapter[<toc>]{<title>}`
3. Second optional argument `[`..`]`, as in `\chapter[<toc>][<header>]{<title>}`
4. Mandatory argument `{`...`}`, as in `\chapter{<title>}`.

To override these, a similar setup to that mentioned above is required:

1. [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

   ```
   \usepackage{xparse}

   \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o o m}{}
   \RenewDocumentCommand{\tableofcontents}{s}{}
   \RenewDocumentCommand{\listoffigures}{s}{}
   \RenewDocumentCommand{\listoftables}{s}{}
   ```
2. LaTeX2e macro redefinitions:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand{\chapter}{\@ifstar\@chapter\@chapter}
   \renewcommand{\@chapter}[1][]{\@@chapter}
   \newcommand{\@@chapter}[2][]{}
   \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@ifstar{}{}}
   \renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\@ifstar{}{}}
   \renewcommand{\listoftables}{\@ifstar{}{}}
   \makeatother
   ```